# Having an issue with Python's unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am learning Python and trying to test a Polynomial class I wrote using unittest. It seems like I am getting different results from directly running a test in Python and running a test using unittest and I don't understand what's going on.

```
import unittest
from w4_polynomial import Polynomial

class TestPolynomialClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.A = Polynomial()
        self.A[1] = 1
        self.A[2] = 2
        self.B = Polynomial()
        self.B[1234] = 5678

    def test_assertNotEq(self):
        self.C = Polynomial()
        self.C[1234] = 5678
        self.C[1] = 1
        self.C[2] = 3
        self.assertNotEqual(self.A+self.B, self.C)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Unittest fails... but I don't understand why. The two polynomials aren't the same. Here are the results from the same test done in a python script using print to compare. The polynomial is different, but same results:

```
A+B =    442x^123 + 12x^6 + 12x^4 + 5x^1 + 0x^0 + -99x^-12 
C =      442x^123 + 12x^6 + 12x^4 + 5x^1 + 0x^0 + 99x^-12 
A+B==C is  False
```

Any help explaining what's going on would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry forgot the error from unittest,

```
    FAIL: test_assertEq (__main__.TestPolynomialClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traenter code hereceback (most recent call last):
  File "add.py", line 18, in test_assertEq
self.assertNotEqual(self.A+self.B, self.C)
AssertionError: <w4_polynomial.Polynomial object at 0x7f2d419ec390> == <w4_polynomial.Polynomial object at 0x7f2d419ec358>
```

And now the Polynomial Class:

```
class Polynomial():

def __init__(self, value=[0]):
    self.v = []
    self.n = []
    temp = list(reversed(value[:]))
    if value == [0]:
        self[0] = 0
    else:
        for x in range(0, len(temp)):
            self[x] = temp[x]
    #self.__compress()

...

def __eq__(self, value):
    temp1 = self.v[:]
    temp2 = self.n[:]
    temp3 = value.v[:]
    temp4 = value.n[:]
    temp1.sort()
    temp2.sort()
    temp3.sort()
    temp4.sort()
    return (temp1 == temp3 and temp2 == temp4)

def __ne__(self, value):
    temp1 = self.v[:]
    temp2 = self.n[:]
    temp3 = value.v[:]
    temp4 = value.n[:]
    temp1.sort()
    temp2.sort()
    temp3.sort()
    temp4.sort()
    return (temp1 != temp3 and temp2 != temp4)

...

def main():
    pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you implemented some kind of `__eq__` for your `Polynomial` class?

Comment: I think we need to see the implementation of the polynomial class... Also just looking at the numbers, you have `self.A[2] = 2` but `self.C[2] = 3` ... I don't know if that has anything to do with it (because I don't know how `Polynomial are supposed to behave in your code ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the implementation with `def __ne__` function in Polynomial class.
assertNotEqual when called, expects a True value when the values passed are not equal. But in this class, you are directly sending the output of temp1 != temp3 and temp2 != temp4.

So, the function should be like this

> ```
> def __ne__(self, value):
>     temp1 = self.v[:]
>     temp2 = self.n[:]
>     temp3 = value.v[:]
>     temp4 = value.n[:]
>     temp1.sort()
>     temp2.sort()
>     temp3.sort()
>     temp4.sort()
>     result = True if not (temp1 != temp3 and temp2 != temp4) else False
>     return result
> ```

Comment: I didn't realize that this is how the __ne__ function should work. I thought if __eq__ returned the result of == that __ne__ would then return the result of !=. Thank you for clarifying this for me.

Comment: Ok, I'm not understanding it. And I don't think it works correctly in that form. It made assertNotEqual happy but when I go back and check it in python it is not correct.

Comment: ([1] != [1] and [1] != [1]) will return False on its own if they are equal, right? So I'm supposed to return True if False? Then the code if A!=B: print('not equal') wouldn't print for the correct inputs.

Comment: Ya, this returns True no matter what.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I didn't understand you. Is it not working for you?

Comment: if (4!= 5):
     print('Not equal'), this prints "Not equal", for if (4!=4): print('not equal'), this does not print anything. Please let me know, if i'm understanding anything wrong

Comment: It's not you. It's me not understanding how it works and what the response is supposed to be when. This actually did work. Turns out that implementing the polynomial class with lists didn't work so well for me so I rewrote it using a dictionary instead for better performance.